# Trouble Successfully Setting OpenTK Window Icon

Tags: c#, opentk

I've been trying to set the icon for my OpenTK window by using the ImageSharp library to load the image from my device and then converting the data to a byte array which I then set as the window icon using the WindowIcon method.

Although this did set the icon to *something*, it doesn't look anything like it should; it should be a comical picture of my cat. However, the result was three black horizontal lines on top of a grey and pink background.

...

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated :)

(I'm using Visual Studio 2019 as my IDE with, of course, the language C#, and .NET Framework 5.0)

My code:

```cs
        public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(string Icon)
        {
            var image = (Image<Rgba32>)SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(Configuration.Default, Icon);

            image.Mutate(x => x.Flip(FlipMode.Vertical));

            var pixels = new byte[4 * image.Width * image.Height];
            image.CopyPixelDataTo(pixels);


            return pixels;
        }

        public Game(int width = 1280, int height = 768, string title = "Window") :
            base(
                GameWindowSettings.Default,
                new NativeWindowSettings()
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Size = new Vector2i(width, height),
                    APIVersion = new Version(4, 6),
                    Icon = new WindowIcon(new OpenTK.Windowing.Common.Input.Image(100, 100, ImageToByteArray(@"C:\Users\xenon\Downloads\BobbilyIcon.png")))
                })
        {
            this.CenterWindow();
        }
```

Sadly, I can't directly include images since I am a new user, so I've attached links to a couple useful images concerning my problem below:

1. The picture of my cat which I am trying to set as the icon:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEMLk.jpg
2. The unexpected result:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvpdz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently I'm a bit dumb. Turns out that when I am setting the icon, using the WindowIcon function, the height and width of the icon must match that of the image being used, which makes a lot of sense now that I think about it. I thought it was some incompatibility between the ImageSharp library used to load the image to memory and copy the data to the byte array and OpenTK.